# Mutation Obeserver not triggering callback for dynamic change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mutation-observers

I have defined two `<div>` elements, one inside another. I listen to the inner `<div>` which has `width:auto;`. When I change the width of the parent `<div>`, I expected the callback from the mutation observer to fire, since the width of the target `<div>` changes. But it's not happening.

What is going wrong?

```js
// Blocker is the element that has a changing display value
var blocker = document.querySelector('#blocker');
// Trigger changes the display value of blocker
var trigger = document.querySelector('#trigger');
// Our mutation observer, which we attach to blocker later
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    // Was it the style attribute that changed? (Maybe a classname or other attribute change could do this too? You might want to remove the attribute condition) Is display set to 'none'?
    if (mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
      alert(window.getComputedStyle(blocker).getPropertyValue('width'));
    }
  });
});

// Attach the mutation observer to blocker, and only when attribute values change
observer.observe(blocker, {
  attributes: true
});

// Make trigger change the style attribute of blocker
trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  $('#d').css('width', '300px');
  //     $('#blocker').css('background-color','red'); 
}, false);
```

```css
#d {
  width: 200px;
}
#blocker {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d">
  <div id="blocker" style="display:none">Stop!</div>
</div>
<div id="trigger">Show blocking element</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divakarvenu/Lru99de0/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You are observing `#blocker` div which is child of `#d` div. But on click you're changing parent attributes (`#d`). `MutationObserver` can only observe element itself or element and subtree ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)). So callback is not triggered because you're simply changing attributes of another DOM element

Comment: yes I am observing the #blocker. However changes in the blocker will change the width of child element #d right.

Comment: Changes in parent, won't cause the child's mutation observer to fire

Comment: So what will be the best way to achieve this?Any idea?